# How to make tabbed section on a shopify template?

Tags: themes, shopify, customization

I am using a shopify theme (Barberry).
I want to add an extra section (consisting of three tabs) on existing product page template (because the template will repeat on different products).
The only option to edit is in the 1st image (under Product Pages option)...
[Product Pages][1]
... but there are only options to link existing products, and I need something more like of a description tabs to create. [Existing options][2]
The question is - how could I edit this template to make same tabs with different content for different products?
Regards,

Comment: You need to use either page builder, meta fields APP or use some custom liquid code to achieve it.

Comment: Thank You for Your reply.
Now I have product photo on left, short description and etc on the right.
I would require three same tabs (but different content) for every product.
Under these tabs there are should be more content.
Maybe someone has ideas how could I do it?

Comment: I think you need to add pseudo comment into product description and use the same into a liquid, like this code I am using it for one website
https://prnt.sc/w4gy5n